# Handling the status bar on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

Is there a goto way to handle the status bar on iOS? For my app, I just want everything to be below the status bar.. but it looks like the only way to do that is to go to every single component and add padding? I would guess theres a way to do it in xcode but I have no clue!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is already a component in `react-native` for the [StatusBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html)

You just need to add it as

```
<YourParentWrapper style={{flex: 1}}>
  <View style={{ height, backgroundColor }}>
        <StatusBar { ...props } />
    </View>
  // ... Your navigation or the child components
</YourParentWrapper>
```

where the height is

```
Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 20 : StatusBar.currentHeight
```

*This will handle your components below the default status bar for all the devices*

Comment: What about IphoneX?

Comment: It is `44pt` instead of `20pt`

Comment: I know but how to handle it?

Comment: There is optimised way of doing it by taking safeAreaView instead of View and it will automatically position the element keeping status bar in mind and for android, give safeAreaView of style {marginTop : Platform.OS === 'android' ? Statusbar.getCurrentHeight() : 0} . *Forgive me for the nameCasing, I just gave the logic : )*